# Changes in aspx and ascx-files not showing

Tags: asp.net, .net, caching, iis

I have a problem with caching of aspx and ascx files in one of my web applications on localhost (windows 7). If I make changes to one of these types of files, for example changing a hardcoded text, no browser picks up this change. I have tried ctrl+f5, and clearing the browser cache. Recompile doesn't help either since no code changes has been done. The only thing that helps is resetting IIS.

I have another web application running on the same IIS instance, where I don't experience this behavior. However, I can't figure out what the difference between those two applications is. I don't publish any files, the IIS sites are pointing directly to the files I edit in Visual Studio.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say recompile do you mean in Visual Studio?

Comment: Is this using the built in Web Development server (Cassini) or IIS 7 proper on your local box?

Comment: Do you have an OutputCache declaration defined in the markup at the top?

Comment: No OutputCache. Using IIS 7 on my local box

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this fixed it self when we went from Subversion to TFS this week.